# EXCEL 64 bit command line vba code

Tags: vba, excel, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I have code to fetch command line arguments when opening up excel book (64 bit; but 32 bit code is also there under #if clause).

So for example, when I run the following line of code at the command prompt, I am expecting to be able to fetch the input string as the command line arguments:

start Excel ".\AwajiPush.xlsm" /p/"kjh%dg.pdf"

(By the way, the reason why "start" is there, is so that it would work in a .bat batch file)

I am expecting to be able to capture 
".\AwajiPush.xlsm"  and 
/p/"kjh%dg.pdf"
as parameters.

The code doesn't do that.

Why is it not fetching the second argument?

I don't know too much about how pointers work.
Is there a piece of code that I can use to capture at least a string that contains both parameters, so that I can parse it.  If it contains more, that is fine.  I can always interpret it, as long as it is consistent.

I put stubs in the program (MsgBox), and I am not sure why the second stub shows blank.

Here is the code:

```
'Put this code in a new module called Parameters

Option Explicit

#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCommandLineL Lib "kernel32" _
     Alias "GetCommandLineA" () As LongPtr

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function lstrcpyL Lib "kernel32" _
     Alias "lstrcpyA" (ByVal lpString1 As String, ByVal lpString2 As LongPtr) As Long

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function lstrlenL Lib "kernel32" _
     Alias "lstrlenA" (ByVal lpString As LongPtr) As Long


 #Else
    Private Declare Function GetCommandLineL Lib "kernel32" _
     Alias "GetCommandLineA" () As Long

    Private Declare Function lstrcpyL Lib "kernel32" _
     Alias "lstrcpyA" (ByVal lpString1 As String, ByVal lpString2 As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function lstrlenL Lib "kernel32" _
     Alias "lstrlenA" (ByVal lpString As Long) As Long

 #End If

 Function GetCommandLine() As String
   Dim strReturn As String
   #If Win64 Then
   Dim lngPtr As LongPtr
   #Else
   Dim lngPtr As Long
   #End If

   Dim StringLength As Long
   'Get the pointer to the commandline string
   lngPtr = GetCommandLineL

   'get the length of the string (not including the terminating null character):
   StringLength = lstrlenL(lngPtr)
   MsgBox StringLength


   'initialize our string so it has enough characters including the null character:
   strReturn = String$(StringLength + 1, 0)
   'copy the string we have a pointer to into our new string:
   MsgBox strReturn


   lstrcpyL strReturn, lngPtr
   'now strip off the null character at the end:
   MsgBox strReturn


   GetCommandLine = Left$(strReturn, StringLength)

 End Function
```

And

```
'Put this code in "This Workbook"

Sub workBook_open()
    MsgBox Parameters.GetCommandLine
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a function to get the command line from the current process:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function w_commandline Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "GetCommandLineW" () As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function w_strlen Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "lstrlenW" (ByVal lpString As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub w_memcpy Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (dst As Any, src As Any, ByVal size As LongPtr)

Public Function GetCommandLine() As String
  GetCommandLine = String$(w_strlen(w_commandline()), 0)
  w_memcpy ByVal StrPtr(GetCommandLine), ByVal w_commandline(), LenB(GetCommandLine)
End Function

Sub Test()
  Debug.Print GetCommandLine()
End Sub
```

Note that you'll have to use the `/e` switch to avoid a redirection to an already launched instance of Excel and thus to keep the provided parameters. For example:

```
excel.exe /e "C:\temp\myfile.xlsm" /p "myparam"
```

Or with `start`:

```
start "xl" excel.exe /e "C:\temp\myfile.xlsm" /p "myparam"
```

But if your goal is to provide some arguments to VBA from a batch, then use an environment variable:

```
Set MyArguments=abcde
start "xl" excel.exe /e "C:\temp\myfile.xlsm"
```

, then to get the argument from Excel:

```
Debug.Print Environ("MyArguments") ' >> "abcde" '
```

Comment: On Windows 11, if i use `set` at command-line (not in a batch) to create an environment variable, then VBA `Environ` fails to return that variable. It returns an empty string. Eg do at command prompt: `set test=abc`

Comment: It seems your solution returns the ENTIRE command line, not just the arguments. In your example, i think we'd have to write some string manipulation to pull everything after `/p`. But do we have to use `/p`. Can we use a character other than `/` or a letter other than `p`?

Comment: i understand now why env vars assigned with `set` aren't available to VBA outside of a batch. `set` env vars are only avail *in process*. With a batch, Excel VBA is running in same batch process as `set`, so VBA can see the env vars.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Microsoft documentation as of 2016, none of the Office products treat the /P switch as a "command line parameter" switch.